# How can I capture/convert HDMI from an HDCP protected input?

Tags: video, hdmi, hdcp

Basically the situation is I have a PS3 and I want to be able to split a lossless HDMI connection to my TV and *something* to a capture card. Using an HDMI splitter I can connect to the TV just fine but my capture card does not read HDCP.

I could use a component splitter but that would prevent me from being able to use HDMI quality video/audio on the TV, and not using HDMI as the source means my setup is more complicated; I have other sources (like my Wii U) where I have to use HDMI.

How how can I record from this HDCP HDMI in? I can take HDMI without HDCP or component video, but my searches have been unable to find to find something that either converts HDMI (with HDCP) to component or takes HDMI and spits out something non-HDCP devices can read.

For the record I know of *one* device that does this: The HDFury4/3. However, the HDFury3 is about $150 above what I'm currently willing to pay, I'm just looking for something barebones. I have seen numerous other devices claiming to do things like convert HDMI to component but they either have multiple 1 star reviews saying "this doesn't work at all" or they have no reviews at all. I'd rather be reasonably confidence before purchasing something like this since it seems like there are a *lot* of solutions which simply don't do what I need them to.

Comment: Some converters use codes which are also on major name brand TV's. These codes are unlikely to be disabled. The trick is finding such a converter. I have seen some HDMI to Component converters on Amazon which are reported to strip in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to Video Production. This answer doesn't really give much information, you could improve it by adding a link to one of the converters that you've seen.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a device that supports HDCP if your output source is utilizing it.  That's the entire point of the system.  The video signal is encrypted and will only exchange the data with a device which can cryptographically authenticate itself as an authorized HDCP receiver. Getting that certificate requires proving that they are going to follow the rules on what can and can't be done with the content (such as not allowing it to be recorded.)

Occasionally codes are cracked, but these codes are then removed from the valid list of codes in future products and they won't work on newer material until another code is broken.  It is also worth pointing out that (unfortunately), if you live in the US at least, such bypassing is illegal in the United States according to the DMCA which specifically prevents bypassing protective measures even if the use would be fair use.

It looks like it may also be possible to connect the PS3 to a non-HDCP device, which would prevent it from using HDCP.  If that is the case, then if you could find a device that isn't HDCP compatible or that can strip the HDCP information, then you could get an unprotected stream and do an end run around DMCA limitations.  You may have to do a soft-reset of the PS3 to get it to recognize a non-HDCP TV if it was previously attached to an HDCP one however since it starts up in the same mode it was in for the previous display.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple actually--running the signal through most HDMI splitters seems to work just fine. I can't be sure if this is a feature of all splitters, but Iv'e got two different models/brands of HDMI splitter and I can record HDMI just fine with 'em.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what worked for you.  The HDMI splitters often do not support HDCP which results in the PS3 not outputting HDCP protected video.  See the third paragraph of my answer for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score -2):

try this its the latest device that's coming out that can get past a lot of issues you are having.

http://www.evsonline.com/atomos-ninja-star-pocket-size-prores-recorder-deck.html

Comment: This still isn't going to capture from an HDCP protected input.  Nothing that is legitimately available on the market is going to provide that functionality as they would have to lie about what they are doing with the decoder keys that they obtain from the governing body of HDCP.